# kendo treeList- change color of child rows depending on certain condition

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treelist

In kendo tree list, how to change the color of entire child row depending on certain data value? 
I tried the method mentioned here: [How to change color of row depending on a row's value in a Kendo UI Grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30796014/how-to-change-color-of-row-depending-on-a-rows-value-in-a-kendo-ui-grid)

it does not work, any other solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through rows in dataBound event and set classes or whatever you want there.

[Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ejasa)

Comment: This works, but when i expand and collapse the child rows, the color is lost. How can i retain it on expand and collapse also?

Comment: Ok, it looks, that kendo rewrites own class after row is collapsed. So if you need change just color, write it directly into css - [example](http://dojo.telerik.com/ejasa/3)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding it in css also is not helping. the colors are lost after row is expanded/collapsed. any other solution?

Comment: Hmm, are you doing it right? If you check example in post above, colors are not lost after collapsed/expanded..?

Comment: Yes, the only change is, i have written custom angular directive to build  tree list. Will that have an impact?

Comment: Ouch, sorry, but I don't know anything about Angular - how it works etc.